# How to avoid optional line breaks in Ocaml's Format pretty-printer?

Tags: ocaml

Is there a clever hack to avoid OCaml's formatters (form Format) from inserting line breaks (specifically those that come from `print_break (@ )`) tags?

I have a somewhat large piece of software that emits lots of messages, and I'd like to use Unix tools on them, like `grep` and `sed`. But the inserted line breaks prevent them from working when the message is split by the formatter. And there are too many formatters in the code for me to individually track all of them and change their "margin" property via `set_margin`.

Such a clever hack might include wrapping Format inside another module, or eventually recompiling OCaml itself, if there is a single central point where the default margin can be set to something like 9999. I tried some experiments such as calling `Format.set_margin` just after main is called, but it doesn't seem to apply to the formatters created by the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let out,flush,_,spaces = get_all_formatter_output_functions ()
in set_all_formatter_output_functions out flush (fun () -> out " " 0 1) spaces
```

If successful it will print spaces instead of newlines.

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution has the same issue than using `Format.set_margin`: it only applies to `Format.std_formatter`, and you'd have to use `Format.pp_set_all_formatter_output_functions` on **all** the formatters used by the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not afraid of brutal solutions:

```
find . -type f -regex ".+\\.ml" -exec sed -i 's/Format/MyFormat/g' {} \;
```

and myFormat file can be

```
include Format
let formatter_of_out_channel c =
  let f = formatter_of_out_channel c in
  pp_set_margin f 9999;
  f
```

and you add the same thing for `formatter_of_buffer` and `make_formatter`.